# Reclassify a raster to floating point values range

Tags: arcmap, interpolation, reclassify

I have an interpolation map for my NDVI data values ranging from 0.16 to 0.83. Example 4 classes, (0.16-0.28,0.29-0.36,0.37-0.53,0.54-0.83). But when I do spline interpolation classification goes from -11 to 16. How can I have same classification class as given in example ? 
I have tried reclassify but it takes only integer values.

Comment: ESRI should still have some form of `remap` available. Tre to google arcmap and remap to see if you come up with anything. Another option is `con` where you can define a set if if/then/else statments.

Comment: Quick and dirty fix would be to multiple input values by 100 before doing the interpolation.